# Can a consumer be accessed after it is closed?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am closing the consumer after everytime it runs `( consumer1.close() )` hoping to avoid unnecessary running until I want the consumer to run again. I do want the same consumer to run again when I call it's run function. But obviously when I run the `consumer1.poll()` again, it says it is closed.

Is there a better way to handle the consumer to run it only when desired? I have also read about `pause()` and `resume ()`, how effective is it in conserving resources?

Comment: Shouldn't a well defined consumer pause on it's own, if and when it's input is depleted? Why bother explicitly halting/pausing it?

Comment: @TreffnonX I am running the consumer only when a set of messages are sent to the topic and closing it as soon as the consumer receives. When the next set of messages are sent to a topic,  i do want to access the same consumer to receive the messages instead of creating a new consumer everytime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you start your consumer make sure to use the same consumer group so that your consumer can continue consuming messages from the point that it was left before being closed down.

---

```
props.put("group.id", "my-consumer-group-id");
props.put("auto.offset.reset", "latest");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have included that. I was wondering if there's a way of accessing the same consumer instead of creating a new consumer each time. Is pause() /resume() the only way?

Comment: @ubuntu_noob Yes. In this case you can use `resume()` and `pause()`: https://kafka.apache.org/0102/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#pause(java.util.Collection)